# How to call abstract class from non parent

Tags: c#, abstract-class, abstract

I have a non abstract class called 'Player', and an abstract class called 'Score' with a subclass of 'Combination'. Within Combination there is and abstract method used in further subclasses.

How can I call my abstract method from the non-parent method 'Player' without making them static?

```
// This is the abstract method within Combination, 
// it uses the face values from rolled dice to calculate the score.

abstract public int CalculateScore(int[] faceValues);

//Array of 'Score's in Player

private Score[] scores = new Score[10];
```

Comment: Can you provides more informations about Player and combination class please ?
What's means faceValues ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. This is access modifier and it was designed to narrow access to a class. To use it in your case, I suggest to change accessibility from `abstract` to `public` of a `Score` class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to implement `CalculateScore` in your derived class by accessing the `scores` field?

Simple answer is, you can't as you designed it that way. `private` modifier makes sure, only your own class can access the field. If you want derived classes to have access to that field, you have to change your modifier to `protected` on the `scores`-field.

If you do not want your derived classes to have access to `scores` directly, you have to implement methods with at least `protected` access, that modify the `scores`-field in a defined way, on the base class.

Answer (score 0):

So your situation:

- `Player` is a normal classs
- `Score` is an abstract class
- `Combination` is an abstract class too that subclasses `Score`. It contains an abstract method `CalculateScore` that you want to call from inside the `Player` class.
- `Player` has an array of `Score`s

You can check if an element in your `Score` array is of type `Combination` then cast it.

```
if(score[0] is Combination)
{
    (score[0] as Combination).CalculateScore(/* arguments here */);
}
```

You might need to rethink how your classes work though. IMHO, Player shouldn't be the one calculating the scores. Maybe use a `ScoreCalculatorService` to handle that.